# DateTimeFormatter type for string java

Tags: java, timestamp, json-deserialization, datetimeformatter

I am receiving timestamp as string as `2021-07-03T09:19:17.83Z[UTC]`. I am using compiling it with pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]XXX` but getting Exception while deserializing.

```
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]XXX", timezone = "UTC")
  private final Date fromTimestamp;
```

Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2021-07-03T09:19:17.83Z[UTC]": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][.SS][.S]XXX"

Is anything wrong with the pattern?

Comment: Using a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to format a `java.util.Date` is not suitable. You should use a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` instead or maybe a `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. If you are using a Java version below Java 6, then switch from `DateTImeFormatter` to a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Hint: This form of a `String` can be parsed with a built-in standard `DateTimeFormatter`: `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`. The result, however, will be a `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. If you really need a `Date`, then you could extract a `java.time.Instant` from the `ZonedDateTime` and use it in `Date.from(Instant instant);`.

Comment: The terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `Instant`.